# Change the month of a Date object without returning a new date

Tags: ruby, date, activesupport

Is there a way to change the month of a `Date` object without returning a new object?

Because `Date.now.change` and `Date.now += 1.month` return new date objects.

Comment: Why would you need this in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "all date objects are immutable" see https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html

Answer (score 1):

No. [From the Date class docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#class-Date-label-Date).

> *All date objects are immutable; hence cannot modify themselves.*

If you really want date objects which appear mutable you can write a wrapper using [Delegator](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html). It would add setter methods and capture the new Date object as the new delegate.

But you should really restructure to work with immuntable objects.